# Adding Header to request that comes from within an Iframe

Tags: authentication, iframe, jwt, http-headers, reverse-proxy

My problem is rather complicated and I dont know if the way we are doing it currently is the correct approach.

**So first a broad overview of the System:**
We have multiple "services" (all web apps like react, streamlit, vue, etc...) each developed by different teams. We now want to enable access to these services for our customers through a single page, on which each customer only has access to some of the services. The services should be embedded into iframes on the main page. The Goal is to do all this without having to change all the services.

Our current solution is now using a reverse proxy with sub request authentication. We are using jwt to authenticate all calls to the backend. When the frontend now requests a service, we include the jwt header, the reverse proxy does the sub request to the backend with the forwarded header and asks if the user is allowed to access the service. This works on a simple html page, but if the frontend of a service does any requests by itself, it fails, because in the request the jwt header is obviously missing.

Is there a way to add the header to all the requests the service does from inside an iframe?
Or is our approach bad, and there is a better solution for this task?

Comment: If you have to add token in request made from iframe, then you have to make some changes to your service, no other way. You cant make any change in api calls made from iframe from its parent container.

Answer (score 0):

This is best solved by separating web and API concerns. For example, using routes like this, where only the second route requires an access token:

```
https://www.product1.com
https://www.product1.com/api
```

**WEB NAVIGATION REQUESTS**

If web resources are static content only, then you don't need to send an access token, since the user is downloading unsecured static resources. The user can then navigate across apps with no problems due to missing tokens.

**API REQUESTS**

If you make all API requests on a route separate to that used for static content, then JavaScript can always attach an authorization header, so sending the access token is reliable.

**WEB HTML + DATA RESPONSES**

If you are returning secured data in HTML responses, then that data will need protecting, so the above approach would not be valid. In that case you will need frontend apps to send cookie credentials to the backend, so that both of the above types of request are secured.

**BROWSER SECURITY**

In fact, these days it is recommended to avoid using tokens in the browser, and use `HTTP-only SameSite=strict` cookies as API credentials. This leads to a [backend for frontend](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-backend-for-frontend-bff) that issues cookies for frontends.

**IFRAMES AND COOKIES**

Iframes are problematic when any action involving third-party cookies or third-party sites is used. Eg. these days you cannot perform an OAuth login from an iframe, since browser restrictions will drop cookies used. Also, providers like Google will not allow their login page to render in a third-party iframe for security reasons.

**SUMMARY**

You may be able to solve your problems by separating the first two types of request above. For least future issues and best login capabilities, aim to avoid iframes if you can. Also, design base URLs that could send first-party cookies as API credentials in future, such as these:

```
https://www.mycompany.com/product1
https://www.mycompany.com/product2
https://www.mycompany.com/api
```